# Aligning Nonlinear bend to grid (MAYA)

Tags: maya

I've been stuck on this problem for a while. I'm trying to make a road piece. Initial size is a plane of 7 x 7. That is the road piece template. Following that I wanted to make a corner piece but it is slightly misaligned from the grid.[image]

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

In your example inner radius of road piece must be equal 9 pieces of your grid size. For example, if grid 1x1cm then road inner radius must be 9cm.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but for example, consider the following situation: https://i.imgur.com/HuO9k0V.png. How would I go about connecting the two road pieces via a corner piece? I'm trying to use the bend tool but for some reason I always get a half a pixel off. (ex: https://i.imgur.com/gnNGJaN.png )

Comment: 1. In first img pivot placed in center of object, on second screen – it aligned with obj bottom
2. Think that you need to tweak Nonlinear deformer attributes